# How to Attach to Process Windows Commands?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, debugging, command

How to Run Visual Studio in Debug Mode while attaching to all w3wp.exe instances using Windows 
Commands?

I have a solution which contains 3 WCF services. Currently, I manually have to go there and attach the debugger to the 3 w3wp.exe processes which are running the WCF services on my local IIS.

How to automate this process using Windows Commands?

Answer (score 0):

by "windows commands" you mean command line?

don't know wether "vsjitdebugger.exe -p" allows for multiple processIDs... (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s68z0b3.aspx)

or may be this might be of help: http://apavan.net/wordpress/?p=29